# R Shiny - How to use local csv file and custom function

Tags: shiny

I started to learn R Shiny recently and I tried to build an shiny app and failed. My problem is: I try to use local csv file on my computer and run simple look up using the custom function, like type in the student's name and return his/her student ID. The following is my codes:

```
ui.R

library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # application title
  titlePanel("FGMC Search Engine"),

  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
  textInput("text",label = h3("Correspondent Search"), value = "Enter Here...")
),

mainPanel(
  textOutput("text1")
)
)

))
```

and then

```
server.R
library(shiny)

# define function for inputing the corr array & input and return channel source
corr_search <- function(corr,input_name){
  # lowercase of input names
  name_lower = tolower(input_name)
  # lowercase of corr names
  corr_lowercase = substr(tolower(corr$TPO.Company.Name),1,nchar(test_lowercase))
  # look up the corresponding channel source accounding to matched corr indexing
  result = corr$Channel.Source[match(test_lowercase, corr_lowercase)]
  # check if search result is Null
  if (is.na(result)){
    result = "Wrong Input! Please Search Again"
  }
  # return search result
  return(result)
}



shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    textInput <- reactive({
    corr = read.csv("C:\\Users\\carl.qin\\Desktop\\Projects\\Modelling & Analytics\\R Modelling\\App-2\\fgmc_correspondent.csv",header=TRUE)
    input_name = input$text
    If(is.na(input_name)){
    input_name = "nothing"
  }
})

result = corr_search(corr,input_name)

output$text1 <- renderPrint({ 

  result
})

}
)
```

I keep getting the error: Object not found. It would be great if someone could help solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `corr_search` you use a variable `test_lowercase` which is nowhere defined (doesn't exist and hence an error).  In `reactive` you use `if`-statement but you have a typo. (Instead of `If` you should have `if`). You should also move `result = corr_search(corr, input_name)` to the reactive expression `textInput` (where you have defined `input_name`) and return a value which you finally pass to `renderPrint` via `textInput()`

Comment: Thank you. I am new to R and shiny, so I made couple of mistakes that I did not notice.

I have changed the codes according to your instructions and it worked. Now I could add more functions to it.